# Convert sql query to nested json

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT att.prod_name, att.prod_group, att.prod_size, obj.physical_id, obj.variant, max(obj.last_updated_date)
FROM Table1 obj
join Table2 att
on obj.prod_name = att.prod_name
where
obj.access_state = 'cr' 
AND obj.variant in ('Front')
AND obj.size_code in ('LARGE')
AND att.prod_name in ('prod_1','prod_2')
group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

The output currently looks like this:

```
prod_name          prod_group       prod_size      physical_id    variant       max
prod_1              1              Large - 2 Oz   jnjnj3lnzhmui   Front      8/8/2020
prod_1              1              Large - 2 Oz   pokoknujyguin   Front      6/8/2020
prod_2              1              Large - 3 Oz   oijwu8ygtoiim   Front      4/2/2018
prod_2              1              Large - 3 Oz   ytfbeuxxxx2u2   Front      7/2/2018
prod_2              1              Large - 3 Oz   rtyferqdctyyx   Front      4/4/2020
```

How can I convert this to a nested json in the query itself ?
Required output: (Variant and max date can be ignored)

```
{"prod_name":"prod_1" , "prod_group":"1", "prod_size":"Large - 2 Oz", "physical_id":{"physical_id_1":"jnjnj3lnzhmui", "physical_id2" : "pokoknujyguin"}}

{"prod_name":"prod_2" , "prod_group":"1", "prod_size":"Large - 3 Oz", "physical_id":{"physical_id_1":"oijwu8ygtoiim", "physical_id2" : "ytfbeuxxxx2u2", "physical_id3" : "rtyferqdctyyx"}}
```

Comment: May I ask, in what language do you use it? Pyhton3, Bash, C++, php. I'd recommend you to do it within that langauge.

Comment: I'm using SQL for data extraction from Amazon Redshift.

Comment: @SreshthaSinhaRoy . . . I don't think that Redshift has JSON constructors.  If you want a *string* formatted as JSON, then you should be clear on that point.

Answer (score 0):

As stated there aren't built in JSON statements for Redshift like there are in BigQuery `TO_JSON()` or SQL Server `FOR JSON`.

So, you are stuck with either writing a conversion yourself in a coding language like Java or Python or writing up a bunch of string manipulation code to "fake it" directly in Redshift.

Something akin to:

```
SELECT CHR(123) || '"prod_name"'|| ':' || '"' || nvl(prod_name,0) || '"' || ',' || 
'"prod_group"'|| ':' || '"' || nvl(prod_group,'') || '"' || ',' || 
'"prod_size"'|| ':' || '"' || nvl(prod_size,'') || '"' || Chr(125) FROM TABLE1
```

The nvl protects you from null values if present.  The nesting aspects get a little harder, but with enough patience you should get there.

Good luck!

Comment: this is what I follow for single jsons and it works. But the part I'm stuck at here is while creating the nested json (the physical id part where number of physical ids keep varying).

Comment: First step is to re-format your original query with subqueries to identify the nested parts first.  And then concatenate them into the larger query.  You're not going to be able to do that in a single query because of the unknown number of product physical ids per product.

Comment: Honestly this is probably going to be MUCH easier with an intermediate coding step between the query and desired output using Java or Python etc..  I think query result is possible, but a LOT of work.